# un able to call another application in to my c++ programe in ubuntu

Tags: g++

Hey I am trying to call(include in to my application) "timbl"- a memory based learner tool for different linguistic features, in to my c++ application. But I can't able to access it. I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 in a VMware environment. My g++ compiler says :fata error timbl: ***no file or directory found.***
how can I make a system call or call using a constructor?
please any one try to address this issue.

There is only one way to call the TimblAPI constructor. Here it is 
***TimblAPI( const std::string& args, const std::string& name ="" );***

but it doesn't work for me 
pls any one try to help me in this regards !

:

Comment: You need to install the development version of package (I think it's called libtimbl3-dev).

Comment: I thank you . u are right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You need to make the question a bit more clear / simple for people to answer it. What to you mean by "call another application"? Do you have an executable that you want to run, or you have an API (library) that you want to access? Is the difference clear to you? From the question we deduce that it is an API.

Supposing it really is the API, what you need to ask is: "how to use a c++ library"?, which is a very important question and certainly has already been asked and answered many times.

In short you need two thing to use an existing API:

- the header files (`.h`) which tell your compiler what interface it can use
- the corresponding compiled binaries (typically .so extension on linux for shared libraries, but could be `.a` for static libraries), which implement the interface

and you must make sure that those are in a place in your computer that the compiler sees them. I will not go in details since this has already been answered many times. Google gives [this](http://www.iram.fr/~roche/code/c++/AddNumbers.html) and [this](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-and-using-shared-libraries-in.html)

As @n.m. sait in the comment, in the Ubuntu repositories you will get both the `.h` and the `.so` by finding a package that starts in `lib` and ends in `-dev`, in this case `libtimbl3-dev`

Also, when you have Ubuntu specific questions, consider asking directly on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Another tip: use an username that is closer to your real name so when you get more repo you can show off more easily and get better jobs! Don't be afraid: people at SO are quite friendly.